# How do I pass two parameters as XML to my controller class on Java Scene Builder?

Tags: java, xml, scenebuilder

I have a class with all the methods needed to control my application but some of these do **require three arguments**.

I am using java scene builder and I'm creating an UI and right now I'm at the login menu scene. I placed a **text_field** to write the username, a **password_field** to write the password and then I have a **login button**, simple enough.

The problem is, **my login function asks for two parameters**: user and password. Yet I can only see the option to name the controller method of choice on action in the scene builder options... I tried changing it in the source but I got a warning that said that **XML methods could only have one or two arguments**. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just figured it out. I had already declared the variables to be injected from the fxml like this:

```
@FXML
private PasswordField pass;
@FXML
private TextField user;

private void login(String user, String password) {
    //method development
}
```

When I tried to login using the injected parameters like this:

```
@FXML
login(user,pass);
```

I would get a message saying that an fxml method could only have 0 or 1 parameter. I have already solved my own issue (or at least I think so) with the following method:

```
@FXML
private void login(ActionEvent event) {
    login(user.getText(),pass.getText());
}
```